# PHP Image not displaying when accessed through controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, image-processing, controller, gd

I am designing my  own PHP MVC

in which any Library file can be used by following steps:

1. Loading the File `$this->registry->load->lib('Image');`
2. Accessing Method from the file `$this->registry->Image->anyMethod();`

The first line loads the file `Image.php` located  in `lib` folder and returns an `instance`
as `$this->registry->Image`

then using that instance, method  `anyMethod()` from the file can be accessed as`$this->registry->Image->anyMethod();`  from`Controller`

PROBLEM is that, I am not able to Output any image !

the following code do not work if accessed from `Controller` but works if directly used !

codes taken from https://www.php.net/imagettftext

```
public function anyMethod()
{
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Please Help , I am stuck.

Note: By adding `ob_clean();` before `imagepng($im);` seems working but without text on the Image .

Comment: Maybe your `Controller` is sending some header infos as well which aren't compatible with your `header('Content-Type: image/png')`?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `exit;` call after destroying the image to prevent any further output being added by your MVC system:

```
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
exit;
```

Also check there are no other `Content-type` headers being issued before your `anyMethod()` call.

Comment: MrCode , Its not working ! but by adding `ob_clean(); ` before `imagepng($im);` it seems working but Text on the Image is not showing , thnx for yr help ..

Comment: I suggest adding `exit;` at the start of `anyMethod()` and seeing what the output is, if there is any output (even a space) then it will cause problems. Also check your error log.